# Obter instância de conexão

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Gostaria de obter a conexão do arquivo dbConnection.js, mas executar a consulta em outro arquivo (DAO).

Estou fazendo um curso NodeJS e o que aprendi é obter essa conexão e usar um método 'gerializado' para executar as consultas. (em dbConnection.js)

No entanto, gostaria de executar as consultas dentro do DAO para o que estou lidando.

O código abaixo representa o meu arquivo dbConnection.js

```
    var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    var assert = require("assert");
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    const dbName = "got";

    // Meu método de obter conexão com banco de dados
    var connMongoDB = function () {

         mongo.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function connectCallback(err, client) {

         // Teste simples para comparar um resultado esperado com um resultado real 
         assert.equal(null, err);

         // Cria uma nova instância db  
         const db = client.db(dbName);


         // Fecha conexão 
         client.close();

      });

     }

     module.exports = function () {
         return connMongoDB;
     };
```

O código abaixo representa meu arquivo UsuariosDAO.js

```
    function UsuariosDAO(connection) {
       this._connection = connection;
    }

    UsuariosDAO.prototype.inserirUsuario = function (dados, res) {

    var collection = this._connection.collection("usuarios");

            switch (dados.operacao) {
             case "inserir":
              collection.insertOne(dados.usuario, dados.callback);
             break;
            default:
             break;
            }

    };

    module.exports = function () {
       return UsuariosDAO;
    };
```

O código abaixo representa meu arquivo cadastro.js (controller)

```
/* Criando a conexão com banco */
var connection = application.config.dbConnection;

/* Instanciando a 'classe' do usuario e passando a conexão para o construtor */
var UsuariosDAO = new application.app.models.UsuariosDAO(connection);

/* Chamando o método para inserção do usuario */
UsuariosDAO.inserirUsuario(dadosForm, res);
```

Error:

```
TypeError: this._connection.collection is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Pelo oq parece, é que não está sendo exportada a instancia da connection, 
estive vendo o seu arquivo de conexão e fiz algumas alterações, para tentar resolver:

```
var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var assert = require("assert");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const dbName = "got";

// Meu método de obter conexão com banco de dados
var connMongoDB = function () {

     mongo.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function connectCallback(err, client) {

     // Teste simples para comparar um resultado esperado com um resultado real 
     assert.equal(null, err);

     // Cria uma nova instância db  
     db = client.db(dbName);
     return db;

  });

 }

 module.exports = function () {
     return connMongoDB;
 };
```

espero que ajude

Comment: Olá amigo, ainda não testei, mas provavelmente não irá funcionar. Veja que o return não pertence a função atribuida a connMongoDB  e sim a função do mongo.connect. Na pratica seria passar esse db para a função continua na variavel connMongoDB e posteriormente exportar essa conexão. Mas obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

eu ate sei qual o curso voce esta fazendo, ele e muito bom porem esta um pouco desatualizado, mas eu posso te ajudar lhe informando que no final do curso, na secao "complemento do curso" voce vera um pdf contento as explicacoes que corrigem e acrescentam novos metodos para solucionar o problem. Mas vou deixar as explicacoes abaixo para voce analisar. Espero que ajude:

```
   var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
   var assert = require("assert");
   const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
   const dbName = "got";
   var connMongoDB = function (dados) {
     mongo.connect(url, function (err, client) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log("Connected successfully to server");
      const db = client.db(dbName);
      query(db, dados);
      client.close();
     });
   };

   function query(db, dados) {
    var collection = db.collection(dados.collection);
    switch (dados.operacao) {
     case "inserir":
      collection.insertOne(dados.usuario, dados.callback);
      break;
     default:
      break;
  }
 }
 module.exports = function() {
  return connMongoDB;
 };
```

Vamos às explicações, no começo do código há a importação do MongoClient que
tem que ser usado na nova versão, e logo abaixo vem a importação do assert, que foi usado
para verificar erros na conexão com o banco de dados.
Na sequência temos as variáveis de credenciais do banco, primeiro a url para
conexão e em seguida o nome do banco de dados que queremos conectar.
Chegamos à função de conexão, a variável connMongoDB continua a mesma, o que
mudou foi seu escopo e os parâmetros recebidos, agora recebemos na conexão um objeto
como parâmetro, com os dados para a conexão e manipulação dos dados, mas não se
preocupe, será explicado mais a frente sobre os parâmetros, dentro da função usamos a
variável importada no começo para chamar o método connect passando alguns dados para
a conexão, e é no callback dessa função que executamos as operações no banco de dados,
dentro da função de callback a primeira coisa que verificamos é se não houve erros na
conexão, se não houve chegamos na declaração da variável db que guarda a referência do
banco de dados que queremos executar as operações, em seguida chamamos a função
query que é quem efetivará as operações, vamos falar dela logo abaixo, e por último para
não serem geradas múltiplas conexões usamos o comando client.close() para finalizar a
conexão.
A função query foi criada para que fosse evitada a repetição de código, pois do
contrário teríamos que criar toda a configuração de conexão para cada operação que fosse
realizada, com a função query podemos apenas inserir um case no switch para cada
operação e dentro do case indicar o que exatamente queremos fazer, no exemplo de código
acima há o case inserir e dentro dele temos o comando collection.insertOne(dados.usuario,
dados.callback), esse comando irá inserir um documento na collection usuarios e em
seguida renderizar uma página, vou explicar na sequência quais são os parâmetros
passados para essa função.
O arquivo UsuariosDAO.js que antes chamava a conexão dentro de cada função
indicando a operação a ser feita e o callback agora apenas cria um objeto de dados e os
passa para a conexão, o novo código ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
    function UsuariosDAO(connection) {
     this._connection = connection;
    }
    UsuariosDAO.prototype.inserirUsuario = function(usuario, res) {
     var dados = {
      operacao: "inserir",
      usuario: usuario,
      collection: "usuarios",
      callback: function(err, result) {
       res.send("olá Marilene");
      }
     };
     this._connection(dados);
   };
   module.exports = function() {
    return UsuariosDAO;
   };
```

Como vocês podem ver dentro da função inserirUsuario criamos um objeto dados
contendo algumas configurações para realizar a operação no banco de dados, esses
índices dentro do objeto devem ser padrão para qualquer operação a ser realizada, são
eles:
 operacao = Deve receber uma string que coincida com o case da função query
 usuario = É um índice variável, dependendo do case você pode passar outros
dados, por exemplo, passar o índice noticia para adicionar noticias, basta ajustar no case
qual dado usar
collection = Deve receber uma string indicando qual a collection que será
manipulada no banco
callback = Deve receber uma função para ser executada como resposta da
execução da operação no banco de dados
E por último chamamos a conexão passando esse objeto.
Usando esse novo modelo, que já foi testado, as operações no banco de dados
ocorrem normalmente.

Comment: Amigo, já tenho acesso acesso a esse documento disponível no curso, mas gostaria de implementar de outra forma. Veja que eu tenho meu método query dentro do arquivo que obtenho a conexão com banco de dados, e na pratica não gostaria de realizar isso, queria tratar as query cada qual em seu arquivo DAO. Para isso preciso exportar a conexão do arquivo que obtem conexão.